# Vector Space Model with Nutch and Solr

Tags: solr, nutch, cosine-similarity, vsm

I'm new to both NUTCH and SOLR, and I have to build a search engine based on these two in my capstone project. Well, what I understand is that Nutch's similarity is LinkRank that does somehow the same work as Google's PageRank and Solr 7.3.1 uses the BM25 similarity by default, and now I have to use the vector space model but I don't know if I have to implement it in both Nutch and Solr or only on Solr. Would you guide me please? ( If I'm understanding things wrong correct it for me please ).

Comment: What is your goal? You can create your own similarity in Solr / Lucene and use that if necessary.

Comment: My supervisor told me that I have to use vector space model with nutch but when I search on the internet I found out that nutch has his own scoring plugin which is LinkRank and I don't know if I do really need to use VSM instead of that plugin or just leave it  and use the VSM with Solr in indexing and querying?
(I tried to modify Solr's similarity which is BM25 by following this tuto :https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity   but it didn't work :/ i still get same results)